# Time.parse .. the hour is not what is expected

Tags: ruby

Why does this say 13 instead of 14?

```
Time.parse('2014-01-08 14:01:00 +0300').hour
# => 13
```

Answer (score 7):

The time is parsed correctly, but displayed in your local time zone.

This happens in my console:

```
Time.parse('2014-01-08 14:01:00 +0300')
=> 2014-01-08 12:01:00 +0100
```

Note the `+0100`.

Answer (score 1):

http://apidock.com/rails/Time/use_zone/class
should help you to get time in correct time zone

Time.use_zone(zone name) accepts block. Inside this block application uses time zone you've provided in zone name

> use_zone(time_zone) public
>   
>   Allows override of Time.zone locally inside supplied block; resets Time.zone to existing value when done.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.